Delete unwanted time dates on the x-axis
For a project I am using soil humidity sensors to test the humidity in a controlled situation in a soil when giving water. Now I want the graph to start when the water was given (shown in the picture below by the enormous increase in values). Everything before there I want to remove from the graph, but since I have limited r experience I am asking it here.

I tried chatgpt but it gave some nonsense

It's better if you can share your code and sample data. If it's a ggplot graph, then you could, for example, add something like + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(lubridate::ymd("2016-01-01"), NA)) which "zooms inon the part starting from, say, 2016. Or you could calculate the required plotting limits in the data and control the limits inscale_x_date()`.

Perhaps adding a reproducible example could make your question more clear.
A ggplot solution is already given in the comments. Here is a rudimentary solution in base R.
Old data:
dat <- c(1:10, 100:90)
plot(dat, type = "l")


New data
new_dat <- dat[-(1:which(dat == max(dat)))]
plot(new_dat, type = "l")


